# SQL Convert all rows of data in a specific column to columns and mapping values in another column to the new columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

THE SOURCE TABLE Looks like this:

h1_ind = 1 indicates a row that contains column names.

```
Source                              
    col1    col2        col3     col4       h1_ind  table_sheet y   w
    Route   CNG/Diesel  Freq     Weekly Miles   1   Summary   2021  Week 1
    a        5          B        6              2   Summary   2021  Week 1
    b        1          1        1              3   Summary   2021  Week 1
    c        5          B        6              4   Summary   2021  Week 1  
    d        1          1        1              5   Summary   2021  Week 1
    Route   CNG/Diesel  Freq     Weekly Miles   1   Summary   2021  Week 2
    a        5          B        6              2   Summary   2021  Week 2
    b        1          1        1              3   Summary   2021  Week 2
    c        5          B        6              4   Summary   2021  Week 2  
    d        1          1        1              5   Summary   2021  Week 2
```

Then I convert to this:
(FOR WEEK 1 ONLY)

```
Data                
IN      column           table_sheet     y      w     value h1_ind
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  a   2
    col2    CNG/Diesel   Summary        2021    Week 1  5   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  B   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  6   5
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  b   2
    col2    CNG          Summary        2021    Week 1  1   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  1   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  1   5
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  c   2
    col2    CNG/Diesel   Summary        2021    Week 1  5   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  B   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  6   5
    col1    Route        Summary        2021    Week 1  d   2
    col2    CNG          Summary        2021    Week 1  1   3
    col3    Freq         Summary        2021    Week 1  1   4
    col4    Weekly Miles Summary        2021    Week 1  1   5
```

I would like to be able to present as desired below.
(FOR WEEK 1 ONLY)

```
Desired output:
table_sheet    y      w      Route CNG/Diesel  Freq  Weekly Miles
Summary       2021   Week 1   a       5         B     6
Summary       2021   Week 1   b       1         1     1
Summary       2021   Week 1   c       5         B     6
Summary       2021   Week 1   d       1         1     1
```

[Desired Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BNDx.png)

how can I do this? Pivot only gives me one row (MAX, MIN) I need all rows to presented.

Comment: You're missing a column on which to group by

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Should your weeks not be week1, week2, etc?

Comment: How do you know which row goes with with which? i.e. why does route `a` have a freq of `B` and not `1`? From your sample data I assume that it is based on the order in which the records appear, but there is no column on which to sort your data, so there would be no guarantee that SQL would get the data in the order you have presented it unless it is told to return it in that specific order

Comment: There are multiple rows per week and all columns can have varying values. There are multiple weeks in the source and when the week changes, column counter h1_ind resets to 1 and begins to incrementally count until the next week is encountered. I have added the h1_ind to the data table, not sure if this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use a `PIVOT`, the key is to make sure `h1_ind` is also part of the grouping and not being aggregated.**

- We use a windowed aggregate to get the header names for each set of values
- Unpivot using `CROSS APPLY`
- Then aggregate back up using `PIVOT`.

```sql
WITH Headers AS (
    SELECT *,
      Col1Header = MAX(CASE WHEN h1_ind = '1' THEN col1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY table_sheet, y, w),
      Col2Header = MAX(CASE WHEN h1_ind = '1' THEN col2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY table_sheet, y, w),
      Col3Header = MAX(CASE WHEN h1_ind = '1' THEN col3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY table_sheet, y, w),
      Col4Header = MAX(CASE WHEN h1_ind = '1' THEN col4 END) OVER (PARTITION BY table_sheet, y, w)
    FROM YourTable t
),
Unpivoted AS (
    SELECT
      t.table_sheet,
      t.y,
      t.w,
      t.h1_ind,
      v.Header,
      v.Value
    FROM Headers t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (Col1Header, Col1),
        (Col2Header, Col2),
        (Col3Header, Col3),
        (Col4Header, Col4)
    ) v(Header, Value)
    WHERE h1_ind > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM Unpivoted
PIVOT (
    MAX(Value) FOR Header IN
    (Route, [CNG/Diesel], Freq, [Weekly Miles])
) pvt;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fbd81c31ce371ebbb6d7a84265bb1b1)

You could also use `MAX(CASE` conditional aggregate here if you want, instead of `PIVOT`.

```sql
WITH ...
SELECT
  t.table_sheet,
  t.y,
  t.w,
  Route          = MAX(CASE WHEN v.Header = 'Route'        THEN v.Value END),
  [CNG/Diesel]   = MAX(CASE WHEN v.Header = 'CNG/Diesel'   THEN v.Value END),
  Freq           = MAX(CASE WHEN v.Header = 'Freq'         THEN v.Value END),
  [Weekly Miles] = MAX(CASE WHEN v.Header = 'Weekly Miles' THEN v.Value END)
FROM Unpivoted
GROUP BY
  t.table_sheet,
  t.y,
  t.w
  t.h1_ind;
```

Comment: This has syntax errors (missing comma, column needs []) and will aggregate to a single row which is the OP's issue.

Comment: You're right, I've modified it now the question has been made clearer